# Using firebase "in" operator results in error

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

Using google Firestore database, I am trying to query a collection using the 'in' operator.

I have closely copied the example from Google, but my code (using golang) results in an error "Firebase invalid operator "in" ".

```
    usernames := []string{
        "5nMUe1hWCu",
        "5n_8e1hwCw",
        "jnM831Qwuk",
    }

    users := database.DB.Collection("User")
    q := users.Where("Username", "in", usernames).Documents(config.CTX)

    for {
        doc, err := q.Next()
        if err != nil {
            t.Log("Throws error here:", err.Error())
        }
    }

// Error is --  invalid operator "in"
```

This closely follows the example code here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership

Comment: Actually - I might have solved it.  I think the go get pulled in an out of date library - changing go.mod to cloud.google.com/go/firestore v1.1.0 *seems* to have solved the problem, but I will confirm if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had an out of date firebase library.

Version v1.1.0 adds support for `in` and `array-contains-any` query operators.